# Determining if algorithm is hierarchical or density allied

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to cluster points in my dataset. The simple steps are as follows:

1. Find the nearest neighbor for each point.
2. Eliminate noise points by setting a threshold for nearest neighbor parameter (those points with large enough nearest neighbor distances are eliminated)
3. Connect all points that are within a user-specified radius of each other.

I haven't tried this yet but do you think this makes sense? What do you think may be the flaws in this algo? Can we classify it as a form of hierarchical clustering? Is it right that this may be akin to Jarvis-Patrick Clustering and Density-based clustering.

Why is jarvis-patrick not hierarchical? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me as if you are reinventing [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).

Your `k` is called `minPts` in DBSCAN, and your threshold is `epsilon`.

OPTICS is a variant that produces a hierarchical result.